# ASP.NET MVC Core DateTime acting weird when I change my Computer Date format and cannot retrieve datepicker value

Tags: c#, jquery, datetime, asp.net-core, jquery-ui-datepicker

My MVC Core will act really weird whenever I change my PC Date Format from `dd/M/yyyy` to `M/dd/yyyy`

Weird as in my `@Html.TextBoxFor` which is `DatePicker`, when selecting dates and submit, the value sometimes can be retrieved by the controller side and sometimes cannot (as in when debug and check the input, there's value there).

Moreover, for example the `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)` will show its value when my PC Date format is `dd/M/yyyy`, and it will be empty if my PC Date format is `M/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is due to date format difference between the jQuery `DatePicker` and the controller. You can change the `DatePicker` date format if you don't mind the dates displayed in the same format as your controller.

Alternatively, you can use the `altField` feature of the `DatePicker` to provide the alternative format. You will need to make your `DateOfBirth` hidden and add another HTML textbox to display the `DatePicker`. When the user selects a date, the `altField` feature will automatically update your `DateOfBirth` with the selected date in the format that you specify. Finally, if you want to initialize the value from you model, use the `setDate` method.

Here is an example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { style = "visibility: hidden; width: 0; height: 0;" })
<input type="text" id="DateOfBirthDisplay" readonly="readonly" />
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#DateOfBirthDisplay").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "d M yy", //The format that you want for the display
            altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", //The format accepted by your controller
            altField: "#@Html.IdFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)"
        }).datepicker("setDate", "new Date(" + Model.DateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy, M-1, d") + ")");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, just wondering though. How do I tackle the issue that it will works on any type of date format environment? Because I need to ensure that the user's pc format won't have any conflict with my files/controller isnt it? Any other method that would solve the problem entirely?

Comment: Using the second solution `altField`, it will work on all machines. The display date is controlled by the `dateFormat` property and you can change it depending on the country or language or whatever you like. The actual format sent to your controller is dictated by the `altFormat` property. Your ASP.Net code will be uploaded to the server and so the environment will not change. If you're worried about changing the server, then use a standard format like the one I used `"yy-mm-dd"`. This should work in any environment even if you change the server settings.

Comment: thanks a lot, but the problem is that, when the value is inserted and the reload, the dateofbirth appear to be empty again, is there a way to make it retrieve value?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. Just wondering that is it possible to configure the that the TextBoxFor not invisible? Because from what you've given me it only can retrieve value and post however, I need the TextBoxFor to be visible to show the datetime value the user submitted before

Comment: You can display it if you like, it doesn't have to be hidden, but then its format is not the one you want for display, and you will have two fields. Instead, it is easy to initialize it from your model when you reload. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a jQuery date picker. It will work for you.

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date_of_birth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class ="m-wrap  datepicker", @readonly="readonly" } })